# Find all four roots of the equation $z^4+1 = 0$ and use them to deduce the factorization $z^4+1= (z^2-\sqrt2z+1)(z^2+\sqrt2z+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all four roots of the equation $z^4+1 = 0$ and use them to deduce the factorization $z^4+1= (z^2-\sqrt2z+1)(z^2+\sqrt2z+1)$

I got $\displaystyle z=(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} = e^{i\left(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}\right)}$ $, k = 0,1,2,3$

But I'm not sure how to proceed with the "deduce the factorization" part, can someone please give me some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get a factorization over the reals, you need to get rid of the $i$'s. To do that, you need to pair up the conjugate pairs. You are using the fact that $(x-z)(x-\overline z)=x^2-2Re(z)x+|z|^2$ all of which is real.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something entertaining to see.
$$x^4 + 1 = x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - 2x^2 = (x^2 +1)^2 - (x\sqrt{2})^2
= (x^2 - x\sqrt{2} + 1)(x^2 + x\sqrt{2} + 1).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $\alpha = e^{i\pi/4}$. Then

\begin{align*}(x - \alpha)(x - \overline{\alpha}) &= x^2 - (\alpha + \overline{\alpha})x + \alpha \overline{\alpha} \\
&= x^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re} \alpha + 1
\end{align*}

But $\operatorname{Re} \alpha = \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the four roots, or solutions, of the equation $r_1, r_2, r_3$, and $r_4$, then $z^4+1=(z-r_1)(z-r_2)(z-r_3)(z-r_4)$.  If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are a complex conjugate pair, and so are $r_3$ and $r_4$, then the desired quadratic functions are $(z-r_1)(z-r_2)$ and $(z-r_3)(z-r_4)$ (when you multiply them out, they'll have real coefficients).

You can use Euler's Formula to write the four roots in $a+bi$ form before you do that, or you can use Euler's Formula after you multiply out the quadratics, it's up to you.  It might be easier to recogize the complex conjugates if you apply Euler's Formula first.